# Angular get status of all children components from parent component

Tags: javascript, angular

I have components 'Parent' and 'Child'.From Parent we can add or remove child. so children are dynamic. in Parent I have rendered Child component in loop like below

Parent.component.html

```
<child *ngFor="let child of children" [data]="child"></child>
```

Now in child component I have added a function called IsValid() to check child is valid or not

Child.component.ts

```
IsValid()
{
  //check validity of component and return true if valid else false
}
```

in parent component I have a button called 'Save' I have to enable that button if all child's are valid else need to disable that button.

So I need a way to call Child components IsValid function for each child component from Parent and then determine the validity result and apply it to Save button to enable or disable

**What I have tried**

**1.**
I have emited valid or invalid result from child to parent and if any childs result is invalid i have disabled save button.

**but problem here is :** if I have added one child, make it valid, save button will be enabled. now I have added another child which is invalid so save button will be disabled but if I remove invalid child save button will be disabled though we have only one child which is valid.. since IsValid event get emmited only if current child get change.

**2.**
I can use something like this

```
<child #varName></child>

@ViewChild('varName') childElement;
```

and then from parent I can call

```
childElement.IsValid()
```

**but** since I have rendered childrens in loop how to give unique name in loop and how to add reference to that unique HTML tag in ts file.

I have created case here [SlackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lrjsfs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please try and make a (minimal) [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) showcasing the issue.

Comment: If you are using form-group then whenever you add a child to it then you can easily check the status of it or I would suggest to use reactive form

Comment: @Jeto created case at given URL .. updated question .. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@angular/core` provides `ViewChildren` and `QueryList`, probably that should help you.

```
<child #varName></child>
import { ViewChildren, QueryList } from '@angular/core';
@ViewChildren("varName") customComponentChildren: QueryList<YourComponent>;

this.customComponentChildren.forEach((child) => { let retult = child.IsValid(); })
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use [@ViewChildren](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren)

In your parent component:

```
@ViewChildren(ChildComponent) children: QueryList<ChildComponent>;

areChildrenValid(): boolean {
   const invalid = this.children.some(c => !c.IsValid());
   return !invalid;
}
```

Note that `children` will be defined after `AfterViewInit` hook.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Component selector:

```
@ViewChildren(ChildComponent) childrenList: QueryList<ChildComponent>;
```

and run a loop through it and determine the validity.